# Зонт или зонтик?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно говорить: зонт или зонтик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально было "зонтик" (от голландского zondek), а потом, для удобства его уже сократили до "зонта".

Answer (score 1):

Сократили не только для удобства, но и по аналогии:  торт — тортик

Answer (score 0):

Зонт — для защиты от дождя, зонтик укропа. Это не правило, просто пояснение.